# What do front end build tools like npm and grunt do?

Tags: npm, build, gruntjs

I'm a noob and have read a couple articles about build tools but want to verify what I know:

Build tools minify and concatenate your front end code into a package of executable files that you can then put on a development server so that it can be served to your backend server (liker rails) to show stuff? Not sure if that's correct, but any help in the most layman terms would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

NPM is the node package manager where from you can install libraries and such.

Yes you can put your front-end .js files together and minify them with grunt to a build directory at the server. You can also turn for example less into css or typescript into js depending on how you configurate your Grunt.

Take a look at their documentation and there is also a quite excellent tutorial there also https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-simple-guide-to-getting-started-with-grunt